# Building android app

Tags: android, android-ndk

hey guys, i am researching android app development, and i cant find much on building an app in C or C++, so my question is, is it possible to build an android app using only C or C++ ?

Comment: Unless you're planning on doing something very low-level, I think you'd have a happier time using Eclipse and Java for this.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: a shared iPhone/Android codebase is enough of a reason to go with NDK. If only Blackberry could come on board as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider one of the other cross-platform services (e.g. [MoSync](http://www.mosync.com/)), but realize that they are also limited in the sense that they give you access to more generic language features. Advanced or new features, such as NFC are not yet supported. Further, if you are planning on deploying the app commercially, you may have to pay them a royalty. You can get a better amount of information at their site.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in the most recent versions of the NDK they've announced such a capability. Before that, you could have an app that's a thin layer of Java on top of a C/C++ NDK core.

The majority of the run-time library is still Java-based, and accessing it from C++ is not exactly straightforward. JNI exposes the Java world to C/C++ callers, but it does not look pretty.

Comment: I think that also android itself must by in version 2.3 to run native c++ apps not only latest NDK.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, using the [Android Native Developers Kit](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/06/introducing-android-15-ndk-release-1.html).

Comment: thanks, but isnt there a limitation, meaning that you cant use it to program the entire app ?